# Thunderbird authentication failures after Firefox update

Tags: thunderbird, authentication

Today May 6, 2020 I was prompted to update Firefox software, which I did. Right after that, I get authentication errors when getting email on Thunderbird. I use email servers from two different commercial hosts and it prompts for passwords for each, but then gives an authentication errors for each email account.
Anybody have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have an update to this.  Since I posted the question, one of the two mail account hosts, in this case Yahoo, sent me an email saying there was a login from Thunderbird, which was me, and now that email account is fine. I still get authentication errors from the other host.  It appears this is not a Thunderbird or Firefox issue.